# Thread initialization in Async Await pattern in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

I have an ASP.Net application, were I heavily use Async/Await pattern. For each thread that is created (or taken from thread pool) I need to make sure that it has right value in TLS (Thread Local Storage) when it’s created and has empty TLS when thread is going back to the session pool (or deleted). Is there any simple way to achieve that?

Comment: This sounds like a bad design. Can you explain why exactly do you need TLS? Normally, you'd use  `CallContext.LogicalGetData/LogicalSetData` with `async/await`. See Stephen Cleary's [Implicit Async Context ("AsyncLocal")](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html).

Comment: What do you need TLS for? Maybe we can suggest alternatives.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not avoid TLS because it is used by a big piece of a legacy code that I'm working with. The same thing is with Async stuff.